# Remote MySQL connection: 'Host does not support SSL connections'

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a C#/.NET application which is connecting to a MySQL server on Linux. I'm attempting to connect via SSL, but I get the error:

```
The host <IP address> does not support SSL connections.
```

How can I enable SSL connections? I do not just want to disable SSL from the client. Is there also a way to access the server securely through MySQL Workbench?

Comment: use SslMode=None in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that you're already trying to connect using SSL, but the host itself doesn't support it. Try disabling that in your client instead. (unless you control the host - then you could enable SSL on that end instead)

Comment: Thanks - I do not control the host, so it seems that I'll have to contact the host instead...